# Which file should I pass as pathname argument of ftok()

Tags: c, linux, queue, ipc, ftok

It is mentioned in ftok() manual

```
key_t ftok(const char *pathname, int proj_id);
```

The  ftok()  function  uses  the identity of the file named by the given pathname **(which must refer to an existing, accessible file)** ...

I am confused about `const char *pathname`.

What would be the best practice for it? 
On my current system I can pass `"/home/Andrew/anyfile"` but it is not possible that other systems, on which my program has to work, will have this file.

How about I use `"/etc/hosts/"` or `"/etc/inittab"` because I am sure all such systems will have these two files? Is it a good idea? Can it cause any problem?

I do not want to ask user to enter filename at the time of execution or pass file name as command line argument.

Is there any other different and better way to decide `pathname`? 
Which way is the best and most reliable one?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Better way for what? Reliable for what? - Maybe it's better to describe a task for which ftok is supposed to be used?

Comment: @Pmod: Actually, I need a queue so that my two programs can communicate with each other. The thing that has actually confused me is that which file I should pass to ftok() which will always be present.  [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155291/which-file-should-i-pass-as-pathname-argument-of-ftok/3155312#3155312) says that it is ok to pass ``/etc`` . If that so then why people pass other files? Isn't it easy and better to pass one of the system files?

Comment: When we had the similar task (organized communication between two programs in linux with the help of message queue) - we used file. The first program (which is like server - always running) creates file with message id, then the second (user program) read msg id from that file and got access to queue.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, generally you would use a file associated with the application itself.

For example, we had an application which loaded a configuration file into shared memory (in a parsed efficiently accessible way - think of an XML file which has been turned into in-memory structures with fast pointers and so forth) and we created the shared memory segment from the `ftok` derived from the configuration file itself.

Worst case, if you have no configuration files for your application, try to use the executable itself. You can be pretty certain that it exists on the system somewhere (since you're running it).

You're also not restricted to files, you can use `/etc` itself or `/tmp` or even `/` if you must.

I say "if you must" because it's a little bit dangerous. The `ftok` call will give you a unique key based on your file spec and your ID. If you use your *own* file such as `/etc/andrew.conf`, you can be reasonably certain that you won't get a clash with any other `ftok`-returned key.

However, if you, and everyone else, decides to use `/tmp` as the file spec part then the only differentiator is the ID. Hence it's a lot easier to get a collision with other keys.

What I've always done is to use the file spec as a truly unique value for my application and then just use the ID for the particular thing I want to create.

So, if I need 27 semaphores and 15 shared memory blocks, they *all* use `/etc/pax.conf` as the file spec and the IDs from 1 to 42 (and my application *knows* what ID relates to what object).

Comment: "you can use ``/etc`` itself or ``/tmp`` or even ``/``  if you must." Is it a bad idea? If it is allowed than why you people didn't use it in your application?

This is confusing me. When we can use ``/etc/hosts`` or whatever system file which is always present, why do we have to look for other ways?

Please explain it. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Probably the best is to use argv[0] of one of your executables. The man page says

```
The resulting value is the same for all pathnames that name the same file, ...
```

so you should be safe, even if your executable is sometimes called through a symbolic link or so.

Comment: Sure! But then how other program will know about it? Pathname and proj_id should be same in both programs so that ftok() generates same key. One of them uses argv[0] so how other will know about it? Kindly elaborate.

Comment: The idea of ftok is that the two programs share common knowledge. I would be supposing that they know the executable names of each other. Then you have the additional key that helps to distinguish several sessions of the same application. In any case you have to share that common knowledge on startup, e.g with an environment variable or so.

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically build a char * for a path based on a config file, or a command line parameter, etc.

Just pass that char * into the function.

Answer (score 0):

Use "." as the first parameter. It will send the current running directory to ftok.